# debmirror not working with Debian experimental release

Tags: debian, mirror

I am trying to mirror the debian "experimental" release on my debian mirror. I am using `debmirror` to do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
GNUPGHOME=/var/lib/debmirror; export GNUPGHOME

debmirror -a amd64,i386 -e rsync --getcontents --diff=none --i18n \
 -v --rsync-options='-rltIL --partial --no-motd' --nocleanup \
 -d experimental -h debian.osuosl.org -r debian /srv/mirrors/debian
```

The errors I am seeing:

```
Mirroring to /srv/mirrors/debian from rsync://anonymous@ftp.us.debian.org/debian/
Arches: amd64,i386
Dists: experimental
Sections: main,contrib,non-free,main/debian-installer
Including source.
Pdiff mode: none
Download at most 200 files per rsync call.
Will NOT clean up.
Attempting to get lock ...
Updating remote trace files (using rsync) ...
receiving incremental file list
./
project/trace/_hierarchy
project/trace/_hierarchy.mirror
project/trace/_traces
project/trace/ftp-chi.osuosl.org
project/trace/ftp-master.debian.org
project/trace/ftp-osl.osuosl.org
project/trace/master
project/trace/syncproxy2.wna.debian.org

sent 343 bytes  received 1,381 bytes  1,149.33 bytes/sec
total size is 1,688  speedup is 0.98
Getting meta files ...
gpgv: Signature made Thu Mar 17 02:09:05 2016 PDT using RSA key ID 46925553
gpgv: Good signature from "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>"
gpgv: Signature made Thu Mar 17 02:09:05 2016 PDT using RSA key ID 2B90D010
gpgv: Good signature from "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>"
Errors:
 Download of dists/experimental/main/binary-amd64/Packages failed
 dists/experimental/main/binary-amd64/Packages failed checksum verification
 Download of dists/experimental/main/binary-i386/Packages failed
 dists/experimental/main/binary-i386/Packages failed checksum verification
 Download of dists/experimental/main/source/Sources failed
 dists/experimental/main/source/Sources failed checksum verification
 Download of dists/experimental/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages failed
 dists/experimental/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages failed checksum verification
 Download of dists/experimental/contrib/binary-i386/Packages failed
 dists/experimental/contrib/binary-i386/Packages failed checksum verification
 Download of dists/experimental/contrib/source/Sources failed
 dists/experimental/contrib/source/Sources failed checksum verification
 Download of dists/experimental/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages failed
 dists/experimental/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages failed checksum verification
 Download of dists/experimental/non-free/binary-i386/Packages failed
 dists/experimental/non-free/binary-i386/Packages failed checksum verification
 Download of dists/experimental/non-free/source/Sources failed
 dists/experimental/non-free/source/Sources failed checksum verification
Failed to download some Package, Sources or Release files!
WARNING: releasing 1 pending lock...
```

The keys in `/var/lib/debmirror/pubring.gpg`:

```
gpg: key B98321F9: "Squeeze Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 473041FA: "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 65FFB764: "Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 46925553: "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 518E17E1: "Jessie Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 2B90D010: "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key C857C906: "Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by the [removal of MD5 and SHA-1 checksums](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2016/03/msg00006.html) from the experimental archive; I doubt `debmirror` supports SHA-256 checksums (it was recently [updated to ignore them](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=808216) instead of looping).

This was tracked as [#818479](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=818479) and fixed in version 2.21 of `debmirror`.